# best way to show 12 columns tables

Tags: mysql, html, css

I have a Mysql table that has 12 columns. Some of them contain 20-30 characters. I was wondering if there are any ways to show all of the columns nicely in one page. It would looks awkward if I just print them all together like this:

column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10 column11

Anyway I can decorate or program those to nicer layout? Thanks.

Comment: This question is centered around the topic of data visualization. There really is not much anyone here can say that will help you beyond minor tips, at least not without knowing a lot more about this particular problem.

Comment: Maybe you should look into `table-layout: fixed`?

Comment: One person's nice is another's meh is another's "zomg kill it with fire".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using something like the jQuery DataTables plugin (http://datatables.net), though considering the amount of data you may also want to truncate the lines (I.E. Text text text...) and on hovering over the cell show the full text.

Edit: One other option would be to have a fixed width table that scrolls horizontally, if you want to show all of the data on that page.